# Dockerfile not copy dist from vue3 build using vite

Tags: docker, jenkins, vuejs3, vite

i'm using Jenkins + docker to deploy my application, this app is Vue3 using Vite.

My docker file build and exist app/dist in build, i checked in jenkins console, but, this not copy to my EC2

```
FROM node:18.16.0 AS build-vue
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./src/Web/Soltel.BackOffice.App/package\*.json ./
RUN npm install --max-old-space-size=1024
COPY ./src/Web/Soltel.BackOffice.App/. .
RUN npm run build --max-old-space-size=1024

RUN ls /app
RUN ls /app/dist

FROM nginx:1.25-alpine
COPY --from=build-vue /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend/backoffice "DONT COPY"
COPY --from=build-vue /app/nginx/backoffice.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/backoffice.conf  "DONT COPY"

EXPOSE 8083
CMD \["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"\]
```

Build in JenkinsFile

```
stage('Build BACKOFFICE') {
    steps {
        script {
            backoffice_app = docker.build('soltelbackoffice', '--no-cache -f ./src/Web/Soltel.BackOffice.App/dockerfilebackoffice .')
        }
    }
}
```

Console Jenkins
[image]

- I just need the dockerfile to copy the files into these folders so that nginx can do its work